# Kafka authentication with Jaas config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, apache-kafka, jaas

I have set up my Kafka jaas config as an external bean in my spring boot application to read my configuration from my application.yaml file.

But I am facing an error reading my jaas keytab file from my yaml file.

Error faced

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user
at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:918) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:738) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:592) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:726) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.login(KerberosLogin.java:103) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:112) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:158) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
```

This is how I have configured my jaas

KafkaJaasConfigurationProperty.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka.jaas")
@Getter
@Setter
public class KafkaJaasConfigurationProperties {
  private Map<String, String> options;
}
```

application.yml

```
kafka:
 jaas:
  options:
   useKeyTab: true
   keytab: keytab-value
   storeKey: true
   debug: true
   serviceName: kafka
   principal: pricipal-value
```

KafkaJaasConfigurationBean.java

```
@Bean
public KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer jaasConfig(
    KafkaJaasConfigurationProperties kafkaJaasConfigurationProperties
) throws IOException {
    var jaasConfig = new KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer();
    jaasConfig.setControlFlag(KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer.ControlFlag.REQUIRED);
    jaasConfig.setOptions(kafkaJaasConfigurationProperties.getOptions());
    return jaasConfig;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems like the keytab file from the jass config you provided is not getting picked up by the KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer .

I can see there is a typo in your jass configuration i.e `"keytab" property value will be "keyTab"`

```
kafka:
 jaas:
  options:
   useKeyTab: true
   keyTab: keytab-value #Try changing this
   storeKey: true
   debug: true
   serviceName: kafka
   principal: pricipal-value
```

I think this should work and it should be able to pick up keytab file.

**SPRING KAFKA EXAMPLE**

But if your are using spring kafka you can also directly give the jaas configuration without creating your own bean for KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer.

Spring kafka example
application.yaml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    jaas:
      control-flag: required
      enabled: true
      login-module: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
      options:
        useKeyTab: true
        keyTab: keytab-value
        storeKey: true
        debug: true
        serviceName: kafka
        principal: pricipal-value
```

Hope this should help you !!

Comment: Yes!, Changing keytab to keyTab was able to work
I am using spring kafka, so will most likely give jaas configuration directly
Thanks!